# Create Oracle procedure error - declare custom type

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to create a procedure in Oracle Express Server (Application Express 2.1.0.00.39) using the web interface.

This is the SQL I'm running via the `SQL Commands` option in the web interface

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure (listOfNumbers num_list, 
                                          v_value varchar2)

IS

  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN

  UPDATE my_table
     SET my_column = v_value
   WHERE my_row_id IN (SELECT column_value 
                         FROM TABLE(listOfNumbers));

  COMMIT;

END;
```

### UPDATE:

Changed `SELECT column_value FROM TABLE` to `SELECT column_value                          FROM TABLE(listOfNumbers)` but now I get the following error:

> PLS-00201: identifier 'num_list' must
>   be declared

### UPDATE 2:

Here is how I created my type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "num_list" as table of NUMBER(38,1)
/
```

Seems the error is being caused on the parameter declaration line:

```
(listOfNumbers num_list, v_value varchar2)
```

Below is the object details as displayed by the Oracle Database Express Edition web interface.

[image]

Comment: There's [no need for PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1171766400346817259), but I don't see the issue with the abstracted code that's been posted.  Does the UPDATE work outside of the stored proc?

Comment: Yes, the Update works. I updated my question, it seems a new error occurs after adding `listOfNumbers` for the nested select statement.

Comment: @rla - I added the `in` to the parameters, still getting the parenthesis error. When I added `FROM TABLE (listofNumbers)` I get a different error. Check the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ...`TABLE(CAST(listOfNumbers AS num_list))`.

The SQL parser simply sees a bind placeholder in place of `listOfNumbers`, and since it's a custom type you need to tell it what type it is.

This will only work if `num_list` has been defined as a type in the schema, not just declared as a type in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: THe type `num_list` is declared in the schema. I updated my question with how I create the typed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works - providing the array type has been declared correctly (see below).  As you are still having a problem I suspect that is where you are going wrong.  But you need to post the code you are using to create the NUM_LIST type in order for us to correct it.

My test data:

```
SQL> select * from my_table
  2  /

MY_COLUMN             MY_ROW_ID
-------------------- ----------
APC                           1
XYZ                           2
JFK                           3

SQL>
```

In order to use a type in a SQL statement we must create it as a SQL object:

```
SQL> create type num_list as table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure my_procedure
  2      (listofnumbers num_list,
  3                    v_value varchar2)
  4  is
  5  begin
  6
  7    update my_table
  8       set my_column = v_value
  9     where my_row_id in (select column_value
 10                           from table(listofnumbers));
 11
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Executing the procedure:

```
SQL> declare
  2    n num_list := num_list(1,3);
  3  begin
  4    my_procedure (n , 'FOX IN SOCKS');
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

And lo!

```
SQL> select * from my_table
  2  /

MY_COLUMN             MY_ROW_ID
-------------------- ----------
FOX IN SOCKS                  1
XYZ                           2
FOX IN SOCKS                  3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was creating the type with quotes around the name:

The following **didn't work**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "NUMBER_T" as table of NUMBER(38,1)
```

When I did it without the quotes and then created the procedure, it was able to recognize it.

The following **did work**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  NUMBER_T as table of NUMBER(38,1)
```

I'm not sure why, but it worked.

Comment: Possibly the quotes forced case-sensitivity on the name, I bet if you declare the type as "NUMBER_T" and then specify the parameter in the exact same way (i.e. listOfNumbers "NUMBER_T") it would probably work